# MissingMethodException when addin class tries to access, but method DOES exist in the latest referenced dll

Tags: c#, add-in, methodnotfound

Lets say I have class as part of my executing code:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    //class definition...
}
```

and I have an add in class:

```
public class Tender
{
    public DataAccess DataAccess { get; set; }
    //other members and class definition
}
```

Well my problem is that I have a consuming (also add in) class like so:

```
public class TenderProcessor
{
    public void Process(Tender tender)
    {
        //having line below uncommented throws the following exception when 
        //this(Process) method is called: 
        //Method not found: 'namespace.DataAccess namespace.Tender.get_DataAccess()'

        this.DoSomething(tender.DataAccess, otherParametersEtc);    
    }
}
```

If `this.DoSomething(tender.DataAccess, otherParametersEtc)` is not commented, i get the `Method not found Exception`, however if I comment the line out, I can actually step into the Process method, hover over the `tender` object and see the value of `DataAccess` perfectly fine.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Check that you're not referencing an out of data version of the assembly containing `Tender`

Comment: Yes, both add-in projects are in the same solution as the DataAccess class and I'm directly referencing the projects, not the dll

Comment: DLL Hell is a standard problem with "addins".  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot, log all binds.

Comment: It could also be that the binary got added to the GAC.  I'm with @HansPassant on using a tool like Fuslogvw to see what's actually being loaded, though it may be easier to use the [Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx) window, since you mention you're debugging.